# Share 4G/LTE modem (wwan0) over eth0 in Linux

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to share my LTE modem connection (wwan0) to my ethernet lan port on my rPi.

I am following this guide, every interface is up and running.

@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:2a:2a:0f  
          inet addr:172.24.1.1  Bcast:172.24.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:423 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:38877 (37.9 KiB)  TX bytes:13468 (13.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:2813 (2.7 KiB)  TX bytes:2813 (2.7 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:7f:7f:5a  
          inet addr:192.168.1.50  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:323 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:485 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30591 (29.8 KiB)  TX bytes:55800 (54.4 KiB)

wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:10:1f:00:00  
          inet addr:100.64.181.186  Bcast:100.64.181.187  Mask:255.255.255.252
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1922 (1.8 KiB)  TX bytes:8367 (8.1 KiB)
```

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
#iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotplug eth0  
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=eth0      # Use interface eth0  
listen-address=192.168.2.1 # Explicitly specify the address to listen on  
bind-interfaces      # Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending things elsewhere  
server=8.8.8.8       # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS  
domain-needed        # Don't forward short names  
bogus-priv           # Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.  
dhcp-range=192.168.2.1,192.168.2.50,12h # Assign IP addresses between 172.24.1.50 and 172.24.1.150 with a 12 hour lease time
```

sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE 

    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         setup.ubnt.com  0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 wlan0
default         100.64.35.177   0.0.0.0         UG    1000   0        0 wwan0
100.64.35.176   *               255.255.255.240 U     1000   0        0 wwan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     10     0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

...If I am connecting my client PC with rPi I get IP address via DHCP, but there is no internet connection. Can not ping (IP, hostname).

Route table after connecting the client:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         setup.ubnt.com  0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 wlan0
default         100.64.35.177   0.0.0.0         UG    1000   0        0 wwan0
100.64.35.176   *               255.255.255.240 U     1000   0        0 wwan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     10     0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

syslog:

```
Jul 26 00:35:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: eth0: carrier acquired
Jul 26 00:35:32 raspberrypi kernel: [  662.708525] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1
Jul 26 00:35:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: eth0: IAID eb:2a:2a:0f
Jul 26 00:35:33 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[794]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth0) 00:0e:c6:d9:b4:b0
Jul 26 00:35:33 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[794]: DHCPOFFER(eth0) 192.168.2.40 00:0e:c6:d9:b4:b0
Jul 26 00:35:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jul 26 00:35:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Jul 26 00:35:34 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[794]: DHCPREQUEST(eth0) 192.168.2.40 00:0e:c6:d9:b4:b0
Jul 26 00:35:34 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[794]: DHCPACK(eth0) 192.168.2.40 00:0e:c6:d9:b4:b0 Adrians-MBP
Jul 26 00:35:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: eth0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.153.193
Jul 26 00:35:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[430]: Registering new address record for 169.254.153.193 on eth0.IPv4.
Jul 26 00:35:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: wwan0: adding default route via 100.64.35.177
Jul 26 00:35:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Jul 26 00:35:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: wwan0: removing default route via 100.64.35.177
Jul 26 00:35:44 raspberrypi ntpd[784]: Listen normally on 8 eth0 169.254.153.193 UDP 123
Jul 26 00:35:44 raspberrypi ntpd[784]: peers refreshed
Jul 26 00:36:01 raspberrypi CRON[1732]: (root) CMD (/home/pi/script/watchdog.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 26 00:37:01 raspberrypi CRON[1751]: (root) CMD (/home/pi/script/watchdog.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 26 00:37:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: eth0: carrier lost
Jul 26 00:37:53 raspberrypi kernel: [  803.801956] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link down
Jul 26 00:37:53 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[430]: Withdrawing address record for 169.254.153.193 on eth0.
Jul 26 00:37:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: wwan0: adding default route via 100.64.35.177
Jul 26 00:37:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: eth0: deleting route to 169.254.0.0/16
Jul 26 00:37:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[760]: wwan0: removing default route via 100.64.35.177
Jul 26 00:37:55 raspberrypi ntpd[784]: Deleting interface #8 eth0, 169.254.153.193#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=131 secs
Jul 26 00:37:55 raspberrypi ntpd[784]: peers refreshed



pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -v -L -n --line-number
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 240 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        1   240 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      wwan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Only wwan0 sharing is not working, If I replace with Wifi wlan0 it's immediately starts working. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         setup.ubnt.com  0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 wlan0
default         100.64.35.177   0.0.0.0         UG    1000   0        0 wwan0
100.64.35.176   *               255.255.255.240 U     1000   0        0 wwan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     10     0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

You have two default gateways. Delete the first:

> ip route delete default via setup.ubnt.com

**OR**

use [policy routing](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html) to configure routing specific traffic via the second gateway (wwan0).

Still, delete one of the gateways from the main routing table. It **will** cause problems.